# Understanding settings of Birch clustering in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am testing out the [Birch clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.Birch.html) algorithm implemented in Scikit Learn. I am a little confused about a statement in the manual; regarding the parameter `n_clusters`, it states

```
n_clusters : int, instance of sklearn.cluster model, default None
```

On the other hand, the initial description of the algorithm is as follows:

> class sklearn.cluster.Birch(threshold=0.5, branching_factor=50, **n_clusters=3**, compute_labels=True, copy=True)

I would take that to mean that `n_clusters` is by default set to *3*, not *None*. This is also what it seems to be doing when I run it.

Am I mis-reading this in some way? What is the logic behind this?

(I guess it does not help that I am not 100 % sure what this setting actually does; I understood it to apply a kind of additional fine-clustering to the outcome of the Birch method. )

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The default value should be 3 instead of None.

When `n_clusters = integer`, the model fit becomes [Agglomerative Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) whose `n_clusters` is set to the value of that `integer`.

When `n_clusters = None`, the further clustering step is not performed and the subclusters are returned as they were before.

[***See #6635 github issue***](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6635)